# Flutter remove image after upload using image_picker package

Tags: flutter, dart

I have managed to upload an image using the image picker package as shown below:

```
final picker = ImagePicker();
Future selectPhoto() async {
  final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  setState(() {
    _image = File(pickedFile.path);
  });
}
```

The image has been displayed on the device where I have a remove button which I can use to remove the image and upload another before saving it.

```
child: Container(
  height: height * 0.2,
  width: width * 0.2,
  child: Image.file(
    _image,
    fit: BoxFit.fill,
  ),
),
```

My question is how can I remove the image from cache as this piece is not working

```
onTap: () {
 setState(() {
   imageCache.clear();
   print('removes $_image');
 });
},
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "not working"?

Comment: Why are you calling `setState` when removing the image from the cache?

Comment: By not working is that the image still remains in the cache

Comment: I don't really really understand how ill go about that. Was just trying my luck

Comment: How are you confirming the image is still in the cache?

Comment: Was printing the path  print(  _image ).Why I used setstate I did not want to reload the page again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding of what the *cache* is compared to explicitly storing a file in memory with your code. Flutter may store images that you use in widgets in a cache so that they may load faster in the future. `imageCache.clear();` does clear the cache and is likely doing it's work in your code. However, your method of checking if the image is still cached is flawed.

`imageCache.clear();` only clears the cache, it does not *delete* the file that you're passing to the `Image.file` widget. This means that `_image`(the file variable you have stored in memory) will persist even over the cache clearing. To truly delete this image you could use the `delete` method or if you just want to stop showing the image, deference the file by setting the file reference to `null`:

```dart
_image = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by calling a method within the button which had set state method where the path was returned back to null

```
clearimage() {
    setState(() {
      _image = null;
    });
  }
```